# What is the correct line delimiter to post multiple measurements to influxDB via WinHttpRequest?

Tags: excel, vba, influxdb, winhttp, influxql

I want to post multiple lines (measurements) of a timeseries to InfluxDB with precision in seconds (precision=s) via VBA and the WinHttp library.

When one measurement is posted everything works fine and the measurement can be found in the db.

When posting multiple lines with \n as delimiter (as specifyed in the docs: [a link](https://influxdbcom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/docs/v0.9/write_protocols/write_syntax/) the result from the server is "unable to parse".

The string  for one line looks like this and can easily be inserted into the db: "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000"

The string for multiple lines look like this: "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000\nd_1_deals value=0 1554336900\nd_1_deals value=0 1554337800d_1_deals value=0 1554338700"

I'm using the "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" object and the post method.
The full code looks like this:

```
Function post_fp_information_to_influx()

sURL = "http://xx.xxx.xx.250:80/write?"
db_string = "db=xxxxxTEST&precision=s"
resulturl_post = sURL & db_string
params = "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000\nd_1_deals value=0 1554336900\nd_1_deals value=0 1554337800d_1_deals value=0 1554338700"

sResult = GetHTTPResult(resulturl_post, "POST", params)
…
End Function


Function GetHTTPResult(sURL As String, Post_GET As String, params As String) As String

Dim XMLHTTP As Variant, sResult As String
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

XMLHTTP.Open Post_GET, sURL, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


XMLHTTP.send (params)


sResult = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
GetHTTPResult = sResult
End Function
```

The error I get when multiple measurements are posted:

"{"error":"unable to parse 'd_1_deals value=0 1554336000\\nd_1_deals value=0 1554336900\\n': bad timestamp"}"

I think the problem is that especially the "\n" is wrongly encoded to "\\n".

I tried different delimiters and approaches but the .send-method keeps sending "\\n", which is not recognized as new line by the API.

Any ideas how to change this behavior? How can I change the delimiter or the Encoding-behavior in order to get the influxDb-API to recognize the line delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` is a C special character to denote the line marker when writing strings in source code. The C compiler replaces this with the actual line marker character, `0x0D`.

On Windows this is often translated in I/O to `0x0D0A`, Carriage Return + Line Feed.

In Visual Basic you have to use `Chr(10)` (`0x0A`) and `Chr(13)` (`0X0D`).

You may need to experiment whether the database wants only the carriage return or also the line feed.

So the string you wrote would become:

```
params = "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000" & Chr(13) & "d_1_deals value= ..."
```

or

```
params = "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "d_1_deals value= ..."
```

Correct/working way:

```
params = "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000" & Chr(10) & "d_1_deals value= ..."
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer @Paul Ogilvie . I tried both strings. 1) "params = "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000" & Chr(13) & "d_1_deals value= ..." and 2) params = "d_1_deals value=0 1554336000" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "d_1_deals value= ..." result both in {"error":"unable to parse 'd_1_deals value=0 1554336000\rd_1_deals value=0 1554336900': bad timestamp"}"  --> seems like the delimiter is replaced by \r\n. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Reading the documentation, I read nothing about sending multiple lines. You can only provide a _file_ containing multiple lines. Anyway. it says at the bottom of the page you must use a newline character (in the file), `Chr(10)`.

Comment: Using only     Chr(10) solved the problem!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error. In my case it was caused by curl:

> --data @file.txt

Should be

> --data-binary @file.txt